# Number of equivalence Relations containing $(1,2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Find the number of equivalence Relations on the Set $A=\{1,2,3 \}$ which contains the Element $(1,2)$.

My Try: Since $(1,2)$ is to be included, so is $(2,1)$ since the Relation should be Symmetric and $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ to be included since it should be Transitive and since the Relation should be Reflexive it should have $(3,3)$.

After this how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two such equivalence relations.  In one, all three elements are equivalent.  In the other, 1~2 (as required) but 3 is not equivalent to any element (other than itself).